# How do I put all this 1200+ line custom javascript into a closure so there are no global vars?

Tags: javascript

The title basically explains the question. The code includes jQuery and a `$(document).ready(function(){...})` which contains 800+ lines in addition to 400+ lines of function declarations. There are also some global vars at the top. I want to put all of this into a closure without affecting (should I say effecting?) how the code currently functions (or at least very little hopefully)!

Comment: Affecting is right :-) http://www.dailywritingtips.com/affect-vs-effect/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without any idea of what you code looks like:

```
(function(window, $) {
   // your code here
}(window, jQuery));
```

But if everything is already in a `$(document).ready()`, then you don't really need to do anything.

Comment: To be on a safe side, i'd pass `window` and `jQuery` as params.

Comment: @ZenMaster how'd you do that??

Comment: `(function(window, jQuery) { // Your code here })(window, jQuery);`

Comment: @Barmar Why do you have to say window, jQuery again at the end?

Comment: @sherlock Those are the arguments that are being passed to the function. They then get captured in local variables named in the parameter list.

Comment: @Barmar Sweet, just got it. You have to invoke it at the end with the params!

Answer (score 1):

`$(document).ready(function` already wraps all your code in a function and hides it from global scope.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var closurevar=22;// will be available withint 
             // the function body but not outside
  console.log(closurevar);//will be 22
  globalVar=33;//not having the var keyword puts this
               // in global scope
  window.globalVar2=44;//more correct way to define global var
                       // jquery defines $ in this way.
});

console.log(closurevar);//will be undefined
// globalVar won't be available until document ready is executed
console.log(globalVar);// will be undefined but will be set after
                       // document.ready has executed
```

Comment: Yeah, but I want the closure to be around the whole document, not just the document ready func.

Comment: I don't think that question was what you think it was :)

Comment: What about var whatver = ['this', 'that', 'theOther']; defined above the doc ready func?

Comment: "The title basically explains the question" Anything in `$(document).ready(function` is not available in global scope.

Comment: @sherlock Anything defined with var is available in current scope so outside a function body it'll be global scope (anywhere where `this` is window). If you leave out the `var` keyword the variable is put on global (window). If you explicitly put the var on window with window.globalVar it's in global scope.